# My AMD Driver update does not work?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I have a question about my pc driver. When i start my game fortnite my Windows keeps saying a text

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrcEc.png]

Already tried to fix it but it does not work. I would appriciate if someone could help me.

My specs are Windows 8.1, 4gb RAM, ATI Radeon 4800.

Comment: So have you updated your AMD display drivers?  The errors message indicates the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Radeon HD 4800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_4000_series#Radeon_HD_4800) is legacy product and got [last driver in 2013](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064).

> After five years of active service, the ATI Radeon™ HD 4000, ATI
>   Radeon™ HD 3000, and ATI Radeon™ HD 2000 Series products reached peak
>   performance optimization on October 15, 2013, and were transitioned to
>   a legacy support lifecycle. No additional driver releases are planned
>   for these products.

Maybe the beta driver from April 2013 works. Otherwise it is time for a new GPU.